# Parsing simple numbers (ASCII) file in C doesn't work

Tags: c, file, ascii

I have a simple file with 64 numbers (0-16) separated with columns, then one special number (0-9) with newline '\n' after it and then another set of 64 numbers, 1 special and newline. ([reference](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/optdigits/optdigits.names) for the file)

```
#define EXAMPLES 100
#define INPUT 64
#define OUTPUT 10

double s_input [EXAMPLES][INPUT]  ={0};
double s_output[EXAMPLES][OUTPUT] ={0};


int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
  FILE* f = open("path/to/file","r");
  if (!f) return 1;

  Read_Data_tra(f, s_input, s_output);
  return 0;
}

void Read_Data_tra(FILE*f, double input[EXAMPLES][INPUT], double output[EXAMPLES][OUTPUT]){
  char buff[3];
  double label;
  buff[2] = '\0';
  for(int i=0;i<EXAMPLES;i++){
    for(int y=0;y<64;y++){
        fread(&buff[0],1,1,f);
        fread(&buff[1],1,1,f);
        if(buff[1] != ','){
            buff[2] = '\0';
            input[i][y] = strtol(buff,NULL,10);
            fseek(f, 1, SEEK_CUR);
        }else{
            buff[1] = '\0';
            input[i][y] = strtol(buff,NULL,10);
        }
    }
    fread(&buff[0],1,1,f);
    fread(&buff[1],1,1,f);
    if(buff[1] != '\n'){
        buff[2] = '\0';
        label = strtol(buff,NULL,10);
    }else{
        buff[1] = '\0';
        label = strtol(buff,NULL,10);
    }
    for(int c=0;c<10;c++){
        if(c == label){
            output[i][c] = 1;
        }else{
            output[i][c] = 0;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This code works flawlessly if I copy e.g. the first line 10 times and let it read. No problem. But if I read the file as it is, it stops working on 5th example. It skips random number. The line goes like 0,0,5,14,4,0... and it SKIPS the 4. Out of nowhere. Then it's offset by 1 and doesn't work for obvious reasons. You may wanna look on the [file](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/optdigits/optdigits.tra) (it's few kB) for yourself.

I know this is gonna be downvoted/closed probably but you know.. I'm desperate and if there should be only one hint I'mma go for it.

Comment: Here's your one hint: Create a [mcve].

Comment: How are you opening that file? From your description it sounds like a plain text file, yet you use `fread` – for one character at a time. Do your problems disappear when you use `fgetc` instead?

Comment: Or use `fscanf`.

Comment: what are your #defines for EXAMPLES, INPUT, and OUTPUT?

Comment: @usr2564301 fopen("path/to/file","r"); I'll try fgetc or fscanf.

Comment: I just ran your code and did not have these issues. I am assuming that INPUT is 64 and OUTPUT is 10. You may want to change this to be reflected in your two loops. `for (int y = 0; y < INPUT; y++) { ... ` and `for (int c=0;c<OUTPUT;c++){ ...` respectively. If INPUT and OUTPUT are not 64 and 10, you could be encountering some indexing issues

Comment: @ChaseWalden That is true. Looks better but makes no difference. Also using fgetc is absolutely the same as what I have

Comment: it appears that the part of the code that reads the 65th special number may also be wrong. You said yourself that the 65th digit is only one character, but it appears that it is searching for one or two characters. this could cause a problem at the end of the file when `buff[1] == EOF`, causing strtol to fail. Not sure if that is the cause of this issue, but is a potential problem. I have yet to be able to replicate your problem though

Comment: Are you on a platform where opening with "rt" would make a difference? Is the text file possibly created on a Windows system, where you are not – or the reverse? This is in addition to `fgetc` as it sounds like your problems are caused by `\r\n` vs. `\n` line endings. It would explain your off-by-one errors.

Comment: @usr2564301. Valid point. This seems to be a `\n` encoded file. I am on a `\n` machine and had no such error.

Comment: @ChaseWalden THIS IS IT!! I've never had experience with this but I thought that reading the other character is just redundant but not necessarily bad. Turns out this caused the issue. You are my savior!! Thank you

Comment: Glad to be able to help. Ill copy my comment into an answer so that this can be closed. I suggest looking into strtok in the future for parsing needs. It would be exactly what you need in this case

Comment: @usr2564301 Also this. I've checked the seek values and it didn't add up to my expectation. There is one byte extra. The "\r". Not reading this value with fread and just changing the seek by fseek solved it. I've also noticed that fseek(...,1,SEEK_CUR) will actually jump 2 bytes when applied ono "\r\n" for some reason. Simply windows.

Comment: Very odd. I opened the file and found that the file only used `\n` returns, not `\r\n`

Comment: @ChaseWalden Then it's just the redundant reading of the newline. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the part of the code that reads the 65th special number may also be wrong.

You said yourself that the 65th digit is only one character, but it appears that it is searching for one or two characters.

This could cause a problem at the end of the file when `buff[1] == EOF`, causing `strtol` to fail.

*(copied from comment to allow this to be closed)*

Comment: I also advise looking at what Ulrich commented. I was not able to replicate this problem, so it was all speculation. I suggest copying your code into a blank program and ensuring it can run on its own before posting. The boilerplate code for how you were opening your file handle, your #defines and the way you declared your two array parameters could all have been relevant.